# How do I prove that a given probability distribution is Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to plot the distribution of a random variable $x$. I got this distribution by marginalising a wishart distribution. When I plot the distribution curve of $x$, it looks like bell shaped i.e. normal distribution. I tried to verify the plot by monte carlo simulation and the distribution that I got for $x$ exactly matches with monte carlo. Now my query is that how can I prove that this distribution is close to normal?

The reason of approximating it with normal distribution is that it makes my further calculations easier.

1. If I show that the second central moment is much larger than the skewness, can I approximate it with normal?
2. Is there any other way to prove that the distribution is close to normal? I do not want to use Kullback Leibler distance or any other metric distance as it is very cumbersome to do the calculations with the marginalised Wishart distribution.

Comment: You could check the kurtosis. If it's not 3 then it can't be normal. Or you could derive the moment generating function. If it's normal it has to have the normal moment generating function.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25568/estimating-the-distribution-from-data/ where the question points at the Shapiro test and the answer points at some graphical plots. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15696/interpretation-of-shapiro-test/ is similar

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to decide *where* you most care about normality...is it the tails of your distribution or the body? If your answer is "both/don't know", then a simple measure of fit is the [Kolmorogov-Smirnov Statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_statistic). It gives the worst-case bound on how wrong you could be if you used a normal distribution for *probability* calculations. If this statistic is $<1\%$, then you're looking pretty good for using the normal.

Now, if you are going to be calculating moments and stuff like that, you need to check that the tails of your distribution are $O(e^{-x^2})$, *in addition* to checking the K-S statistic above, otherwise, your moments could be way off.